# Using findpeaks and minpeakdistance in MATLAB to find peaks separated by distance rather than index

Tags: matlab, graph, analysis, figure

I'm trying to get the x-coordinates of peaks in a MATLAB figure (example attached). I've been using `findpeaks`, but it doesn't seem to like the fact that I'm plotting points rather than lines.

I won't always have two peaks. Sometimes I'll have three, sometimes I'll have one. Multiple peaks will always be separated by at least 1/4 of the range of x, and peaks will always be at least twice the noise level.

Here's what I would expect would work:

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(yData,...
                       'SortStr','descend',...
                       'MinPeakDistance',floor(range(xData)/4),...
                       'MinPeakHeight',floor(max(yData)/2)...
                       )
```

Instead of getting two peaks, I get four all bundled around the first peak:

```
>> locs

locs =

    6774      166785      326792      486799
>> xData(locs)

ans = 

-96780.787939025         -96770.1800919265   
-96770.8959353367        -96771.6117787468
```

I assume that MinPeakDistance is working on the in xData indices rather than the data itself. How do I get it to use the distances between peaks instead of the distance between indices of peaks?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findpeaks` doesn't know anything about the x-coordinates or what you have plotted.  You need to specify `MinPeakDistance` in terms of indices.  Here's an example:

```
xData = -100:1:-1;
yData = rand(1,100);
yData(10) = 100; % peak
yData(11) = 99; % not a peak
yData(50) = 100; % peak
yData(51) = 99; % not a peak
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(yData,...
                       'SortStr','descend',...
                       'MinPeakDistance',floor(length(yData)/4),...
                       'MinPeakHeight',floor(max(yData)/2)...
                       );


xLocs = xData(locs);

pks =

   100   100


locs =

    10    50
```

Comment: so, if my indices are all messed up (that is, `6774 166785 326792 486799` are all around the same xData), I need to sort my xData into ordered indices before finding the peaks, then find the peaks, then map my ordered indices back to the original indices?

Comment: Yes. Find peaks returns indices and you'll need to find a way interpret them in terms of your x-coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've accepted Molly's answer, I've found my own that's slightly less hassle, but less elegant:

```
  %find all peaks significantly above noise floor
  [pks,locs] = findpeaks(yData,'SortStr','descend','MinPeakHeight',floor(max(yData)/2));
  xLocs = xData(locs);           

  %find number of peak clusters
  numPeaks = length(unique(round(xLocs/100)));

  %find locations of numPeaks peaks
  [pks,locs] = findpeaks(yData,'SortStr','descend','npeaks',numPeaks);
```